# Can I keep crafting mods for my non legendary clothes?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I'm playing Cyberpunk 2077 patch 1.5, on Xbox Series X.

Until yesterday, I was able to craft *epic quality* mods, such as "Armadillo" for my clothing. I don't know the reason (it could be some quest I finished, or because I reached level 40), but now I can only craft the *legendary* versions.

In the crafting menu, filtering by "Attachments and mods", I have:

- Clothing mods, *legendary* quality: "Resist!", "Street smart" and "Armadillo".
- Weapon mods, *legendary* quality: "Crunch", "Pacifier" and "Penetrator".
- Weapon mods, *rare* quality: "Combat amplifier".

The game doesn't allow to modify an item with a better quality mod. My clothes are mostly *epic* tier (which is worse than *legendary*), so I can't no longer apply the mods that I craft.

**Is there any way in which I can keep crafting mods for my *epic* quality, *non-iconic* clothes?**

I would be OK with any of these options, if they're possible:

- Crafting the lower tier mod. Can't find the option, but maybe it's there?
- Crafting the *legendary* tier mod, and then downgrading it. I don't think it's possible.
- Improving my clothes to *legendary* tier somehow (I mean the same items I have now, not replacing them).
- Improving the *crafting-spec* of the clothes to *legendary* tier, and recrafting the items.
- Unlocking a perk or a skill level that allows to use any quality mod in any item, if such perk exists.
- Anything else (no cheats or exploits, please).

Please keep in mind I'm talking about *non-iconic* clothing, so upgrading it will only improve the stats, not the quality tier.

Comment: Please separate your two questions into two separate posts

Comment: Rewrote the question. It should be clearer now that I'm asking only one thing :)